# PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: linux

```
 [PDOException]
    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

Please explain me why I got this error?

Comment: Please elaborate, explain a use case that leads to this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could get this message if you restart the MySQL server, or if another process that deletes the tables you were using.

Another possible cause is that the `max_allowed_packet` value in your `my.cnf` file is too small.